# How to handle browser prompts in Chrome

Tags: prompt

I am working with Java application. When i run my script new window is opening with Prompt message as shown in the picture. I want to click HTML5 button it will open Canvas application. I tried Alert & window handling both not working.

How to Click that button through selenium?

[image]

Comment: sorry i could not able to see image so i uploaded 3 times. Kindly help me to resolve this issue

Answer (score 0):

Try using this when browser is opened :

```
  Robot robot = new Robot(); 
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_TAB);  
  Thread.sleep(1000);
  robot.keyPress(KeyEvent.VK_ENTER);
```

It will perform normal keyboard operations by first going to "Use HTML5" button by pressing "Tab" key and after that it will press "Enter" key.
    I do not know if that will help you or not. But you can give it a try.